# How to update and older version of electrum on ubuntu 17?

Tags: electrum, ubuntu

I used the following commands to install electrum:

- sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-pyqt5 python3-pip
- sudo pip3 install https://download.electrum.org/3.0.5/Electrum-3.0.5.tar.gz

For latest tar files: https://electrum.org/#download

In the future, how would I go about updating electrum? What command would I use to update?

Also, where are the electrum files installed that contains my private keys and wallet?

[image]

Comment: running **sudo pip3 install https://download.electrum.org/3.1.0/Electrum-3.1.0.tar.gz** from the website works perfectly. when updating. See Preview: http://prntscr.com/inr5c4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how would I go about updating electrum? What command would I use to
>   update?

There are couple of ways to do it:

- If you downloaded the official package (`tar.gz`), you can run electrum from its root directory, without installing it on your system; all the python dependencies are included in the 'packages' directory. To run Electrum from its root directory, just do: `./electrum`
- There is also [PPA](https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/electrum) package repository, but I think they didn't update it.
- I've a shell script, this script check the github source, download the last version and save the backup of an old wallet. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/fishbullet/9991dff30ddd53f40b39a86f4a2b930b).

> where are the electrum files installed that contains my private keys
>   and wallet?

On the Linux machine, there is the folder `~/.electrum` which contains your wallet, configs and other.

Comment: thanks. where is the electrum program installed?

Comment: @Patoshi perhaps in `/usr/local/lib/` if its pip3 installed programm.

Answer (score 0):

> In the future, how would I go about updating electrum? What command would I use to update?

The same way you installed it i.e. `sudo pip3 install <tarball>`

pip3 will uninstall the old version and install the new version for you.

I strongly suggest installing using pip3 instead of relying on your distro's repos. Electrum has a very fast release cycle and most distros don't keep up with the latest. Installing from source will get you the latest and greatest. I also strongly recommend checking the gpg sig before installing. [This script](https://github.com/BitcoinsPakistan/electrum-install) automates all that for you.

Wallet files are stored in ~/.electrum/wallets. You can also backup the file via file menu > save copy. More about backing up an Electrum wallet [here](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/how-to-backup-your-electrum-wallet/).

In case you are wondering wallets don't get removed when you uninstall electrum. This is to prevent accidental loss of funds. When you update Electrum it automatically picks up your wallet from the default location I gave above.